# How to find remaining cooldown time with std::chrono?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I want to measure the time left before the next action. I have an online game, where I want to measure spawn times.. Time left before next spawn.

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - std::chrono::hours(12) - std::chrono::minutes(22));

char buf[100] = {0};
std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&now_c));
return buf;
```

Above you have my actual code.

For example, the last spawn time for a boss is 12 hours and 22 minutes ago.
I want to measure how much time left before the next spawn (from now).
I want the time format to be hour:minutes:seconds. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: add clarifications from comments
The spawn happens everyday at the same time

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing... In the example, you mention you _already know_ that the next spawn time is in 12h22min...
Do you mean that you know the the _next_ spawn will be in 12h22min and want to then create a timer untill then? Or do you simply want to print the seconds?

Comment: Let's say the mob has been spawned, now. Which is day 1, hour 12. Now i need to calculate in how much time will be next spawn. Since now when spawn was done, until next day same hour 12.   Each time when a player login it send the left time until next spawn. I want the server to calculate the left time until next spawn will happen, and send this data to the player.

Comment: Does the mob always spawn at the same time everyday?
Is there a 24 hours cooldown between the spawn?

Comment: Yes it will spawn same time everyday, each day hour 21:00 for example.. Yes there's a 24h cooldown.  From 21:00 to next 21:00

Comment: Ah. This makes more sense now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Samelessly stealing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593250/4522147):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

std::string
display(std::chrono::nanoseconds ns){
    std::ostringstream os;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>> days;
    auto h = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(ns);
    ns -= h;
    auto m = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(ns);
    ns -= m;
    auto s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(ns);
    os << std::setw(2) << h.count() << ":"
       << std::setw(2) << m.count() << ":"
       << std::setw(2) << s.count();
    return os.str();
};

int main(){
    auto cooldown = std::chrono::hours(24);    
    
    // You need to save the last spawn time when it happens.
    // This here simulate 1 hour has passed
    auto last_spawn_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - std::chrono::hours(1);

    // Compute the next spawn time
    auto next_spawn = last_spawn_time + cooldown;

    // Finally, find the std::duration to show how much time left:
    auto next_spawn_in = next_spawn - std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Next spawn in: ";
    auto duration = display(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(next_spawn_in));
    std::cout << duration << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, since you mentionned you were doing this in a server, you might want to double-check that the timezone won't play tricks on you

Comment: Amzing answer, i'm gonna try it right away.

Comment: I hope it can help you! :) I modified a bit the display function so it only prints the _hour:minute:seconds_ and returns a string. This seamed to fit your question better

Comment: @IrinelIovan don't hesitate to tell me if it didn't work :)

Comment: I'll try tommorow and come back, right now i'm working to another stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to measure the time left before the next action... For example, the last spawn time for a boss is 12 hours and 22 minutes ago.

You don't need to measure anything - it seems you already know it:

[time left to spawn] = [time between spawns] - [time since last spawn]

abstractly, these three values all have the same type: Time duration. Luckily, and as @JeanBenoitHarvey notes, `<chrono>` represents durations and perform arithmetic between durations (in various resolutions and base representation types). So you can literally write:

```
auto time_left_to_spawn = time_between_spawns - time_since_last_spawn;
```

in C++ with `<chrono>`, and when the two elements on the right-hand side of the equation have a type of `std::chrono::duration<T, Ratio>`. Which they would, if you're using the chrono library reasonably.