# How do I convert chrono::steady_clock::duration to ostream?

Tags: c++

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const TimedEvents& t)
    {
        os << "Execution Times:\n--------------------------\n";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < t.nEvents; i++)
        {
            os << os.width(21) << t.events[i].name << ' ';
            os.width(13);
            os.setf(ios::right);
            os << t.events[i].duration << os.unsetf(ios::left) << ' ' << t.events[i].units << endl;
        }
        cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

        return os;
    }
```

In the above code, `os << t.events[i].duration` won't work because I can't convert duration to ostream. Duration is a `chrono::steady_clock::duration` and Visual Studio says there are no '<<' operators that match.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590821/convert-stdduration-to-human-readable-time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to convert it to `std::ostream`, you want to convert the duration object to a type that can be inserted into an output stream (like an integer, double, ...).

```
os << t.events[i].duration.count();
```

Or overload the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, chrono::steady_clock::duration duration)` to define how you want it to be displayed:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, chrono::steady_clock::duration duration)
{
    os << "duration was " << duration.count() << ", ";
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[A streaming operator for `std::chrono::duration` is coming in C++20](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.io) (still being implemented by the major vendors).  If you would like, you can use this [free, open-source, header-only preview of C++20 chrono](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  The preview works with C++11/14/17:

```
#include "date/date.h"  // add this

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const TimedEvents& t)
{
    using date::operator<<;  // add this
    os << "Execution Times:\n--------------------------\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t.nEvents; i++)
    {
        os << os.width(21) << t.events[i].name << ' ';
        os.width(13);
        os.setf(ios::right);
        os << t.events[i].duration << os.unsetf(ios::left) << ' ' << t.events[i].units << endl;
    }
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;

    return os;
}
```

This will output both the *value* and the *units* of the duration.

If you  would rather do it yourself, you can use the `.count()` member function to get the value, and if you know the units, print out something to signify that.  If you don't know the units, you can use the `duration`'s nested types `period::num` and `period::den` to get the numerator and denominator of the fraction of seconds the duration represents.  For example for milliseconds, that would be 1 and 1000 respectively.